# Playing videos one by one issue : Android SDK

Tags: android

I have an requirement in which I want to play the second video immediately once first video gets completed finishing. I have implemented this functionality, but the issue I am seeing is appearance of black screen between video transition.  I am trying this on Galaxy S device (1 GHZ processor, 512 MB RAM).

I have used VideoView, SurfaceView, but still issue is not resolved.  It looks like video preparation is taking time. I have used recommended videos format (H264 encoded videos with around 500 bit rate). Considering device Galaxy S  1 GHZ processor, this issue should not occur.

Any related pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks!
Nilesh

Here is the code:

Here is the code. I am having two videos : video1 and video2. After playing first, I am loading Video2.  Here I am using videoview

```
package com.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    VideoView video;
     Toast toast;
    boolean first;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video1);
        video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
        first=true;
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(first){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.video1);
            video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            video.setVideoURI(uri);
            video.start();
            first=false;
        }
        else{
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                    + R.raw.video2);
            video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            video.setVideoURI(uri);
            video.start();
            first=true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setView(image);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using? That might give us a hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: How long is the delay between the first and second videos?

Comment: I have also faced this constraint and there is no solution to this using in built VideoView or surfaceView. Try using some c or c++ based video players and integrate them using NDK.

Comment: Delay is around a second, but it is noticeable between video transition.

Comment: Hi Mudit, do you have any reference to C/C++ video player library used on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't just splice the two videos together into one video in an editor? Do they have to be separate files?

Also, have you tried using multiple VideoViews? Right now, when video1 finishes, you're telling your VideoView to load up video2 from the resources which might be taking some time. If you had two VideoViews in the Activity (one for video1 and one for video2) and loaded both of them up during onCreate, you could hide the one that wasn't currently playing. In 'onCompletion', instead of loading video2 you would just hide the VideoView for video1 and make the VideoView for video2 visible and start playing it.

Something like this (not tested):

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    VideoView video1;
    VideoView video2;
    Toast toast;
    boolean first;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        video2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video2);
        video2.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        video2.setVideoURI(uri);
        video2.setVisibility(HIDDEN);        

        video1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.video1);
        video1.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        video1.setVideoURI(uri);
        video1.start();

        first=true;
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(first){
            video2.setVisibility(HIDDEN);
            video1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            video1.start();
            first=false;
        }
        else{
            video1.setVisibility(HIDDEN);
            video2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            video2.start();
            first=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this already i.e. using two video views. It did not work for me.  I can not use the approach of combining videos as my application might contain more than 15 videos and application scalability point of view, I want separate videos.

Comment: Hi Nilesh did you achieve the black screen problem solution? Did you got the solution?